# How do I solve the issue of multiple initialization when using malloc?

Tags: c, malloc

I need to use malloc to allocate memory to one instance of struct game and store the return pointer in p_game_info for a game.

This is the code for the relevant function in game.c

```
void play_game()
{
    struct game *p_game_info = 0;
    struct game *p_game_info = malloc (sizeof (struct game));
}
```

This is the code for the struct in game.h

```
struct game
{
    char board[3][3];
    char playerNames[2][MAX_NAME_LEN];
    int status;
    boolean finished;
};
```

In VS I am getting the following error message

```
error C2374: 'p_game_info': redefinition; multiple initialization
```

I have been searching online for a similar problem but have been unsuccessful.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: the problem is not malloc but you declared the `p_game_info` twice in the function play_game()

Answer (score 1):

Solution is there in error message itself, don't declare & initialize every time, declare `p_game_info` only once.

```
void play_game() {
    struct game *p_game_info = malloc (sizeof (struct game));/* declaration & initialization both at a time */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the errors says, you are initializing the pointer twice in your function. Also, you are declaring it also twice..

try doing both only once, something like.

```
void play_game()
{
    struct game *p_game_info = 0;                 // declaring and initializing once
    p_game_info = malloc (sizeof (struct game));  // allotting memory.
}
```

Alternatively, you can combine both in one line.

```
void play_game()
{
    struct game *p_game_info = malloc (sizeof (struct game));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix it to:

```
void play_game()
{
    struct game *p_game_info = 0;
    /* struct game* */ p_game_info = malloc (sizeof (struct game));
}
```

The error means what it actually says. You initialized (defined) twice the same variable `p_game_info`.

According to the standard, you may have multiple *declarations*, like here (which should compile perfectly)

```
struct game *p_game_info;
struct game *p_game_info;
struct game *p_game_info;
struct game *p_game_info = 0;
....
void play_game()
{
    p_game_info = malloc (sizeof (struct game));
}
```

But it must have **only one** definition (initialization)!

More about *declaration* and *initialization* in C is in this link: [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410632/5218277)

**EDIT**

As noticed by *Weather Vane*, the example of multiple declarations, is OK only at a file scope - and is called a "[tentative declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/extern)"

Comment: You can only do this at file scope - and is called a "tentative declaration".

Comment: @WeatherVane You are right, I'll move it out of the function scope.